# Why ansible skips hosts even after using add-host module in bootstrapping EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-ec2

Ansible - 1.9.3

Dynamic inventory is used.

Bootstrapping an EC2 instance and adding the instance to host using add-host, but it skips the plays for the newly created hosts. But when running the play next time, it finds the host and starts executing.
Here is the snippet,

```
hosts: localhost
tasks:
  - name: something
    ec2: this module will create instances
  - name: adding hosts
    add host: name=(name of the new instance)
hosts: new host
tasks: 
  - something
```

The above is just an example .This is the scenario.

Comment: Is that a typo in your question? The module name is `add_host`, not `add host`. Notice the `_`.

Comment: That's just a pseudo type. Not the real code

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into this frustrating issue before.  You need to add the host to a group as well.  The `add_host` module says the `group` argument is optional, but it doesn't seem to be.  Once you do that, you should be able to target the group you have added the host to.

Comment: I tried adding group(groupname) too in the add_host module. It seems it is a bug. the bug has been filed in ansible repo. here is the link [ansible-issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/12677)